# Status my initiated workflows

Tags: workflow, status

hope you can help me.
We are using SharePoint 2013.

We have one standard workflow created with Nintex. There are several approval steps included in the workflow. The respective tasks are saved in a list "Workflow Tasks".

How can I get an overview of the status for the workflows I started/initiated?
I know the view "Active Tasks" and "My Tasks". But these views are showing only the workflows with regards to a approver. I want to have a status overview of the workflows I requested/initiated.

Thanks,
Iggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow history can be requested in the Nintex development area:

- open your library with the workflow you have in focus
- choose from the ribbon menu: Library => Workflow Settings => Managing workflows with Nintex
- click on the workflow name you like to explore
- choose "view history" from the sub menu
- you'll see a list headed "Workflowstatus" grouped by outcome / status (it could last a bit to open this view - depends on how often it has been started)

For those who like pure data mining: the NintexWorkflowHistory list is a hidden list normally adressed by http://yoursite/Lists/NintexWorkflowHistory . It's not comfortable to go this way if you're not knowing exactly what to look for. Furthermore the views can easily be overflooded by exceeding threshold.